# Rendering large number of objects in realtime using RealityKit or Metal

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, metal, realitykit

I am currently working on a project where I need to render a large number of objects in 3D. However, I have encountered performance issues when attempting to render a significant number of objects.

[image]

To provide some context, I have tried looping through my simd3 array, creating sphere meshes, and adding model entities one by one. Unfortunately, this approach is quite slow a. For instance, it takes several seconds to render just 50 objects.

I am seeking solutions or guidance on how to optimize the rendering process to achieve significantly faster results.
Ideally, I would like to render around 10,000 objects in approximately 1/90th of a second. Furthermore, I am curious to know if it is possible to render even larger quantities, such as 100,000 or even 1 million objects, in realtime.

Are there any recommended techniques, approaches, or alternative frameworks that can help me?

Answer (score 1):

For optimal performance you will want to use instancing.

Here is a [tutorial](https://metalbyexample.com/instanced-rendering/) on the subject.

It is also worth mentioning that running in a simulator will not offer the same performance as on actual hardware.

Comment: For RealityKit, it appears there isn't a way to do instancing. When I clone a `ModelEntity`, and add it to scene, I get 1 draw call per `ModelEntity` – even if I don't change any properties on the entity, etc. I'm surprised there's not a batching mechanism of some sort.

I was looking at RealityKit for a 3D `.nonAR` game, I guess this is another area where SceneKit wins, despite being so much older.

Comment: I should add that I am sharing/using the same MeshResource and not creating one per ModelEntity too

Comment: It's buried a bit, but on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arkit_in_ios/adding_visual_effects_in_ar_quick_look_and_realitykit# it says:

> While utilizing features to present virtual content effectively, take steps to keep the AR experience responsive. Because each model mesh results in a draw call, for best results, limit the number of meshes in a USDZ file to around 50. To reduce draw calls while maintaining the same amount of geometry, merge objects that share a material.

Comment: For instancing, have you investigated `MeshResource/Contents/instances`? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/meshresource/contents-swift.struct/instances ? Each instance gets its own transform https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/meshresource/instance This seems promising but I have not tried it myself yet. The documentation for this feature is surprisingly hard to find, even if you already know it exists. I'm curious what the effect on draw calls is.

Comment: Also it's worth noting that if you're calling `MeshResource/generateSphere(radius:)` to create the spheres in your screenshot, each sphere will consist of 8,064 triangles.